# Substract two times, total hours and working hours

Tags: php

I want to substract two hours:

a. 40:00:00
b. 31:18:00

I want this result 09:42:00. How can i achieve this?

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: That still isn't a question.

Comment: *How can i achieve this?* Try something, show us your attempts! Without doing something you will never get to your goal!

Comment: ... by having a 1 hour time shift (Time zones?)

Answer (score 1):

The result is 08:42:00 (40:00:00 - 31:18:00 = 08:42:00 not 09:42:00)

I think this solves:

```
$lasthour = '40:00:00';
$firsthour =  '31:18:00';

//explode first hour
list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $firsthour);
//convert to seconds 
$secFh = ($h * 3600 + $m * 60 + $s);

//explode last hour
list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $lasthour);
//convert to seconds 
$secLh = ($h * 3600 + $m * 60 + $s);

$sub = $secLh - $secFh;

echo gmdate("H:i:s", $sub);
```

Comment: And how we can add this time into date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: Try this `strtotime("+1 minute",$yourDate) or strtotime("+1 hour",$yourDate)`

Comment: Not working in case of $lasthour = '40:00:00';
$firsthour =  '05:18:00';